# problems passing gl with Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a button class thats created from within the onSurfaceCreated method in my glSurfaceView; It takes gl as one of its parameters so it can properly draw. Im having an issue passing gl to an overlay class, which looks like a pin in the google maps app. If i call makeOverlay() in my button's constructor it draws perfectly, if i call it anywhere else all i get is a white square. They are all on the same drawing thread. Anyone know what im missing? Thanks.

Comment: i found out you can only pass gl from the 3 override methods, onSurfaceCreated,onSurfaceChanged, and onDrawFrame; beyond that it wont work anymore. Rephrasing my question, how could i trigger a new object to be made properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the GL context is not made current outside of those methods.

You can just make a abstract representation of your object and draw it in your onDrawFrame method. That's what you should be doing anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the GL context inside a static variable to be able to access it from anywhere within your code.

Comment: If you call it out of the gl thread it probably won't work as intended.